# Finding an asymptotic expansion for $\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{1}{1+\frac{k}{n}}$

Tags: summation, asymptotics, euler-maclaurin

It is well known that an asymptotic expansion of the *n*-th harmonic number is $$H_{n}= \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k} \sim  \ln(n) + \gamma + \frac{1}{2n} -\frac{1}{12n^{2}} + O(n^{-4}).$$

How could we find an asymptotic expansion for the sum $ \displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{1+\frac{k}{n}}$ to a similar order?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let $ \displaystyle f(x) = \frac{1}{1+\frac{x}{n}}$.

Using the [Euler-Maclaurin summation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula#cite_note-4), we get

$$ \begin{align} \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{1}{1+\frac{k}{n}} &\sim \int_{0}^{n} \frac{1}{1+\frac{x}{n}} \, dx + \frac{f(n)+f(0)}{2} + \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{B_{2m}}{(2m)!} \left(f^{(2m-1)}(n) -f^{(2m-1)}(0) \right) \\ &= n \ln \left( 1+\frac{x}{n} \right) \Bigg|^{n}_{0} + \frac{\frac{1}{2}+1}{2}  + \frac{1}{6} \left(\frac{1}{2!} \right) \left(-\frac{1}{n} \frac{1}{(1+\frac{x}{n})^{2}} \right) \Bigg|^{n}_{0} \\ &- \frac{1}{30} \frac{1}{4!} \left( - \frac{6}{n^{3}} \frac{1}{(1+ \frac{x}{n})^{4}}\right) \Bigg|^{n}_{0} + \mathcal{O}(n^{-5}) \\ &= n \ln (2) + \frac{3}{4} + \frac{1}{16n} - \frac{1}{128 n^{3}} + \mathcal{O}(n^{-5}) \end{align}$$

For $n=20$, the above approximation is correct to $8$ digits after the decimal point.

Answer (score 5):

This sum is quite intriguing  and invites additional scrutiny. We will
now present an alternate  derivation of the asymptotic expansion which
is totally  unorthodox and employs divergent series,  yet produces the
correct result.

We are studying
$$S_n = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{1+\frac{k}{n}}.$$

Rewrite this as
$$S_n = \sum_{k=0}^n \sum_{q\ge 0} (-1)^q \left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^q
= \sum_{q\ge 0} \frac{(-1)^q}{n^q} \sum_{k=0}^n k^q.$$

The term for  $q=0$ is special and  we now extract it from  the sum to
obtain
$$n+1+\sum_{q\ge 1} \frac{(-1)^q}{n^q} \sum_{k=1}^n k^q.$$

We will now work with  the remaining sum and apply Faulhaber's formula
which we recall says that
$$\sum_{k=1}^n k^q =
\frac{1}{q+1} \sum_{j=0}^q (-1)^j {q+1\choose j} B_j n^{q+1-j}.$$
Substitution now yields (note that $q+1 > j$ so $q \ge j$)
$$n+1 + \sum_{j\ge 0} 
\sum_{q\ge j}  \frac{(-1)^q}{n^q} (-1)^j 
{q+1\choose j} \times \frac{1}{q+1} \times B_j n^{q+1-j}
\\= n+1 + \sum_{j\ge 0} 
(-1)^j B_j n^{1-j}
\sum_{q\ge j} \frac{(-1)^q}{q+1} {q+1\choose j}.$$

There is one  more correction to make: we included  the term for $q=0$
and $j=0$  which has value $n$ and  we need to subtract  out this term
because we already accounted for it, which finally leaves us with
$$ 1 + \sum_{j\ge 0} 
(-1)^j B_j n^{1-j}
\sum_{q\ge j} \frac{(-1)^q}{q+1} {q+1\choose j}.$$

We  have now  arrived at  the moment  where we  will  employ divergent
series. The inner  sum does not converge but we can  assign a value to
it evaluating
$$Q_j(z) = \sum_{q\ge j} \frac{z^q}{q+1} {q+1\choose j}.$$
and setting $z=-1.$ Note that
$$Q_0(z) = \sum_{q\ge 0} \frac{z^q}{q+1}
= \frac{1}{z} \sum_{q\ge 0} \frac{z^{q+1}}{q+1}
= \frac{1}{z} \log\frac{1}{1-z}.$$
For $j>0$ we get
$$Q_j(z) = -\frac{z^{j-1}}{j} +
\sum_{q\ge j-1} \frac{z^q}{q+1} {q+1\choose j}
= -\frac{z^{j-1}}{j} +
\sum_{q\ge j} \frac{z^{q-1}}{q} {q\choose j}
\\= -\frac{z^{j-1}}{j} +
\sum_{q\ge j} z^{q-1} \frac{(q-1)!}{j! (q-j)!}
= -\frac{z^{j-1}}{j} +
\frac{1}{j} \sum_{q\ge j} z^{q-1} \frac{(q-1)!}{(j-1)! (q-j)!}
\\ = -\frac{z^{j-1}}{j} +
\frac{1}{j} \sum_{q\ge j} z^{q-1} {q-1\choose j-1}
= -\frac{z^{j-1}}{j} +
\frac{1}{j} \sum_{q\ge 0} z^{q+j-1} {q+j-1\choose j-1}.$$
This sum is the Newton binomial and we finally have
$$-\frac{z^{j-1}}{j} +
\frac{z^{j-1}}{j} \sum_{q\ge 0} z^q {q+j-1\choose j-1}
= -\frac{z^{j-1}}{j} +
\frac{z^{j-1}}{j} \times \frac{1}{(1-z)^j}.$$

We will take  $Q_j(-1)$ as the value of the  inner sum that determines
the coefficient on $n^{1-j}.$
We get for $j=0$ the value
$$Q_0(-1) = \frac{1}{-1} \log \frac{1}{2}
= \log 2.$$
For $j\ge 1$ we obtain
$$Q_j(-1) = -\frac{(-1)^{j-1}}{j} +
\frac{(-1)^{j-1}}{j} \frac{1}{2^j}
= \frac{(-1)^{j-1}}{j} \frac{1-2^j}{2^j}.$$

Putting it all together we obtain the asymptotic expansion
$$1 + n B_0 \log 2 - B_1 \times \frac{-1}{2} +
\sum_{j\ge 2} 
(-1)^j B_j n^{1-j}
\sum_{q\ge j} \frac{(-1)^q}{q+1} {q+1\choose j}
\\= n \log 2 + \frac{3}{4}
+  \sum_{j\ge 2} 
(-1)^j B_j n^{1-j} 
\frac{(-1)^{j-1}}{j} \frac{1-2^j}{2^j}
\\ =  n \log 2 + \frac{3}{4}
+  \sum_{j\ge 2} 
B_j
\frac{1}{j} \frac{2^j-1}{2^j}  n^{1-j}.$$

Actually computing this expansion we get
$$n\log 2 +3/4+1/16\,{n}^{-1}-{\frac {1}{128}}\,{
n}^{-3}+{\frac {1}{256}}\,{n}^{-5}-{\frac {17}{4096}}\,{n}^{-7
}+{\frac {31}{4096}}\,{n}^{-9}\\-{\frac {691}{32768}}\,{n}^{-11}
+{\frac {5461}{65536}}\,{n}^{-13}-{\frac {929569}{2097152}}\,{
n}^{-15}+{\frac {3202291}{1048576}}\,{n}^{-17}+\ldots$$

This expansion is amazingly precise.  Using up to the $n^{-17}$ term
we get for $n=20$ the approximation
$$14.6160676358538815006576381306$$
while the exact value is
$$14.6160676358538815006576332145.$$

Using the terms up to $n^{-23}$ we get for $n=50$ the approximation
$$35.4086089655097601622322941347$$
while the exact value is
$$35.4086089655097601622322941347$$
i.e. at thirty digits precision we can no longer tell the difference.

I do think  this calculation is remarkable in  that it makes extensive
use  of  divergent  series to  obtain  a  result  that appears  to  be
perfectly correct.

Comment: Thank you very much! Very inspiring!

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{red}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
Since the series has a closed expression in terms of the *Digamma Functions*, it's interesting to check the expansion by means of the asymptotic behavior of those functions:
\begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{1 + k/n}}
=n\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{k + n}
=n\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\pars{\frac{1}{k + n} - \frac{1}{k + 2n + 1}}
\\[5mm]&=n\bracks{\Psi\pars{2n + 1} - \Psi\pars{n}}\tag{1}
\end{align}
where $\ds{\Psi}$ is the [Digamma Function](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_258.htm) and we used
[${\bf 6.3.16}$](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_259.htm). With
[${\bf 6.3.5}$](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_258.htm), expression $\pars{1}$ becomes:
\begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{1 + k/n}}
=n\bracks{\Psi\pars{2n} - \Psi\pars{n}} + \half
\end{align}
With the
[Digamma Asymptotic Expansion](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_259.htm)
${\bf 6.3.18}$:
\begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{1 + k/n}}
\sim n\times
\\[5mm]&\braces{\!\!\bracks{%
\ln\pars{2n} - \frac{1}{4n} - \frac{1}{48n^{2}} + \frac{1}{1920n^{4}}
-\frac{1}{16128n^{6}}}\!\!
-\!\!\bracks{%
\ln\pars{n} - \frac{1}{2n} - \frac{1}{12n^{2}} + \frac{1}{120n^{4}}
-\frac{1}{252n^{6}}}}
\\[5mm]&-\half
\\[1cm]&=n\bracks{\ln\pars{2} + \frac{1}{4n} + \frac{1}{16n^{2}} - \frac{1}{128n^{4}} + \frac{1}{256n^{6}}} + \half
\\[5mm]&=\color{#66f}{\large n\ln\pars{2} + \frac{3}{4}
+ \frac{1}{16n} - \frac{1}{128n^{3}} + \frac{1}{256n^{5}}}
\end{align}